# Why an electron "rotate" around the nucleus at a speed close to the light one?

Tags: particle-physics, speed-of-light, electrons, atoms

Why an electron "rotate" around the nucleus at a speed close to the light one?
I mean where he gets all this energy?
One DOES NOT simply approach the speed of light AFAIK.

Comment: Who said that it does? Non-relativistic QM describes light elements **very** well.

Comment: I close this question as _unclear what you're asking,_ but the question is really closed because it rests on a false premise. In other words, in order to re-open this question, OP (or somebody else?) should add a published reference that backs up his premise.

Answer (score 4):

(1) if it were a classical system, the correct word is "revolve" rather than "rotate"; *the Earth **rotates** every 24 hours and **revolves** around the sun (approximately) every 365 days*

(2) since it's not a classical system, the notion of an electron *revolving* around the nucleus is suspect.  Indeed, for S orbitals, the *orbital angular momentum is zero.*

So, where do you get this notion that your question is based on?

Comment: That's why I put " around rotate.
I don't remember where I have read it...

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع, perhaps some more research is in order then?

Comment: Of course taking the Fourier transform of the position distribution yields a momentum distribution from which you can determine if the semi-classical approximation is adequate to your needs.